# Is there a way to get eauto to properly invoke econstructor?

Tags: coq

I'm working through CPDT, going along with the exercises from here: [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/670Fall12/)

In this case I'm on 17, here: [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/HW17.v](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/670Fall12/HW17.v)

The main relevant definition of an inductive type is here:

```
Inductive has_type : context -> expr -> type -> Prop :=
| T_Unit : forall ctx, has_type ctx UnitE UnitT
(* Using a separate "t = ..." parameter here eases automation: *)
| T_Var : forall ctx n t, n < length ctx ->
                          t = nth n ctx UnitT ->
                          has_type ctx (Var n) t 
| T_Abs : forall ctx t1 e t2, has_type (t1 :: ctx) e t2 ->
                              has_type ctx (Lam t1 e) (Arrow t1 t2)
| T_App : forall ctx e1 e2 t1 t2, has_type ctx e1 (Arrow t1 t2) ->
                                  has_type ctx e2 t1 ->
                                  has_type ctx (App e1 e2) t2.
```

The exercise is that the proofs are already written, and it's up to the student to manipulate the hint database to get them to go through automatically...but I'm hitting a weird case I don't know how to think about.

```
Hint Constructors has_type.

Example stlc_app : has_type nil (App (App (Lam UnitT (Lam UnitT (Var 0)))
                                           UnitE) UnitE) UnitT.
  eauto 10.
Qed.
```

This doesn't work...but oddly, this does:

```
Example stlc_app : has_type nil (App (App (Lam UnitT (Lam UnitT (Var 0)))
                                           UnitE) UnitE) UnitT.
  repeat econstructor.
Qed.
```

Furthermore, I tried different values for `eauto n` and it's clear that it is just returning instantly...

I believe that `eauto` uses `eapply x`, not `econstructor`, but `eapply T_App` also works...so I'm not sure why it is short circuiting.

Note that when I run `Hint Constructors has_type`, I get this message:

```
The hint T_App will only be used by eauto, because applying T_App would leave variable t1 as unresolved existential variable.
```

But we are in fact using eauto, so I'm not sure what is going on. And the `info` command that CPDT mentions doesn't work anymore.

I tried the following hint:

```
Hint Extern 1 (has_type _ _ _) => econstructor.
```

But that didn't work, which is weird because `repeat econstructor` in fact solves the target.

I'd love some advice on better understanding why the `Hint Extern` doesn't work, as well as why the `eauto` isn't properly invoking the constructor. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After applying constructors 5 times, we come up with a goal

```
0 < length (UnitT :: UnitT :: nil)
```

and this is where `eauto` stucks.

This kind of simple arithmetic proposition can be solved by `eauto` with `arith` hint database.

So `eauto 10 with arith` can solve stlc_app.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I did try `Hint Extern 1 => omega`...any clue why the arith database would do it, but omega wouldn't dispatch it?

Comment: I'd try by hand, but I'd expect you need `simpl` before `omega` (so `Hint Extern => simpl in *; omega`. And today I'd use `lia` instead (after the needed imports), since `omega` is getting deprecated. Neither tactic does much except from arithmetic solving, often not even unfolding definitions.